# chrome.identity in browsers other than chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, opera, opera-extension

I have made a chrome extension that uses `chrome.identity` but now I want to add support for other browsers (e.g. `opera`).
Obviously, most features like `getAuthToken` do not work: I have to use `launchWebAuthFlow`. But there is one problem: it does not give the `access_token` actually.

In `google developers console` I have to apps: `chrome app` with the id `...dtrfe...` and a `web app` with id `...gbo04...` and some `client_secret` and `redirect_uri`s.

If I use
`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({"interactive": true, "url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=...&redirect_uri=https://o**fgjcoofkoe.chromiumapp.org/&response_type=code&client_id=...gbo04..."}` (chrome app), I get a `redirect_uri` mismatch error (I cannot even set it in the console). So it does not seem like a correct way.

If I use
`chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow({"interactive": true, "url": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/v2/auth?scope=...&redirect_uri=https://o**fgjcoofkoe.chromiumapp.org/&response_type=code&client_id=...dtrfe..."}` (web app), I get a code but it is not an access_token: to turn it into an `access_token` I have to send a request with my `client_secret`. Obviously, it does not seem like a good way to do client-side (in a browser extension where every user can find the source code and get the secret credentials of my app).

How to handle such situations correctly? Is there a way to 'remake' `chrome.identity.getAuthToken` in browsers other than chrome (using `chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow`) without exposing my secret credentials? Or in such cases I must make a server that will get the code from extension and respond with the information needed?

Comment: Try https://github.com/eight04/webext-launch-web-auth-flow